# Clipping mask inverse?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a fairly simple image:

[image]

I wish the middle transparent area to be a bit bigger:

[image]

What shall be my next step to cut all the white "clipping mask" from the underneath layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no inverse vector mask functionality. But you can still do something similar (if this is actually all you need, otherwise see *Note below).

Double click the ellipse shape layer, and set the Layer Style: Blending Options as follows. Knockout = Deep, and move the Blend if grey: Current Layer, right hand slider to the left a bit until it cuts out.

[image]click to see larger

***Note** If your intent is to actually put something inside the vignette, such as another image, then you could instead simply clip the image to the white ellipse layer. This will make it look like it's behind the original vignette, as if there is a cut out. To clip a layer to another, move your mouse over the line between the two layers in the Layers panel, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click it.

[image]